# How to use Powershell to work with the registry?

Tags: powershell, registry

Apparently my Google-fu is weak when it comes to finding thorough yet understandable tutorials on how to work with the Windows Registry from within a Powershell script (as opposed to interactively within a PS shell). The fact that the registry uses a "key-name-value" structure but is somehow accessed "same as a file system directory" just plain confuses me.

Suppose I have a registry that is:

```
HKLM
  KeyA
    NameA1=ValueA1
  KeyB
    NameB1=ValueB1
  KeyC
    NameC1=ValueC1
    NameC2=ValueC2
    NameC3=ValueC3
    KeyCA
      NameCA1=ValueCA1
    KeyCB
      NameCB1=ValueCB1
```

What's the most correct way* of doing the following:

1. Checking if `KeyA` exists?
2. Checking if `NameB1` exists?
3. Getting the name- and the value-parts of the first/only item within a key (say, `NameC1` and `ValueC1`), given that I don't know the name of that item (only the path of the key)?

   - Currently, I crudely use `Get-ItemProperty` to obtain `@{name=value}` and apply some string splitting.
4. (More generally:) Iterating over all names in `KeyC` (so `NameC1, NameC2, NameC3`), given that there may be zero or more items?
5. Iterating over all subkeys in `KeyC` (so `KeyCA, KeyCB`), given that there may be zero or more items?
6. Renaming a key (say, `NameB1` to `NameB2`); or creating a new key with the same type and value, and deleting the old one?
7. Changing a value (say, `ValueC3` to `ValueC5`), given that I know the key and name?

I know I can use Get-ChildItem for some things, and Get-ItemProperty for others, but I don't understand it and am fumbling about with little luck. How do I best apply these for my listed needs?

*(Related, yet off-topic: what's the equivalent of 'pythonic' for Powershell?)

Comment: Being phrased differently than my other questions here, I did expect some backlash; and currently at -1, this seems to be the case. I understand and hope you'll communicate with me _why_ you disapprove, because the number alone is not helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've attempted to answer each of your questions below, but I recommend that you read the [help file about PS Providers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847791.aspx) (the abstraction layer that maps the registry as a file system):

```
help about_Providers
```

---

> Checking if KeyA exists?

Since the registry is mapped like a file system, you can use [`Test-Path`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849776.aspx):

```
PS> Test-Path HKLM:\KeyA
True
```

---

> Checking if NameB1 exists?

Name-value pairs are treated like item properties by the Registry provider, check if [`Get-ItemProperty`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849851.aspx) returns anything:

```
PS>[bool](Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\KeyA -Name NameB1)
True
```

---

> Getting the name- and the value-parts of the first/only item within a key (say, NameC1 and ValueC1), given that I don't know the name of that item (only the path of the key)?

Again, registry can be treated like a file system and you can use `Get-Item` to retrieve any key. The difference from an actual file system is that the object returned is of type [`Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey(v=vs.110).aspx) and not `System.IO.FileInfo`. A registry key object has a [`GetValueNames()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvaluenames(v=vs.110).aspx) method that you can use to retrieve the value names:

```
PS> $RegKey = Get-Item HKLM:\KeyC
PS> $RegKey.GetValueNames()
NameC1
NameC2
NameC3
```

To just get the first one:

```
PS> $RegKey = Get-Item HKLM:\KeyC
PS> $ValueName = $RegKey.GetValueNames() |Select-Object -First 1
PS> Get-ItemProperty $RegKey.PSPath -Name $ValueName |Select-Object $ValueName
```

if you want *just* the value, use `-ExpandProperty` with [`Select-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx):

```
PS> Get-ItemProperty $RegKey.PSPath -Name $ValueName |Select-Object -ExpandProperty $ValueName
```

---

> Iterating over all names in KeyC (so NameC1, NameC2, NameC3), given that there may be zero or more items?

Again, use the `GetValueNames()` method:

```
foreach($ValueName in ($Key = Get-Item HKLM:\KeyC).GetValueNames())
{
    "{0} has value {1}" -f $ValueName,$Key.GetValue($ValueName)
}
```

---

> Iterating over all subkeys in KeyC (so KeyCA, KeyCB), given that there may be zero or more items?

Use [`Get-ChildItem`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) as you would in a regular file system:

```
PS> Get-ChildItem HKLM:\KeyC |Select -ExpandProperty Name
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\KeyC\KeyCA
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\KeyC\KeyCB
```

---

> Renaming a key (say, NameB1 to NameB2); or creating a new key with the same type and value, and deleting the old one?

For *keys* (ie `KeyC`), use [`Rename-Item`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849763.aspx)

```
Rename-Item HKLM:\KeyC -NewName KeyD
```

For *value names* (ie `NameB1`), use `Rename-ItemProperty`:

```
Rename-ItemProperty HKLM:\KeyB -Name NameB1 -NewName NameB2
```

---

Bonus question:

> *(Related, yet off-topic: what's the equivalent of 'pythonic' for Powershell?)

I don't think PowerShell has been around for long enough for an equivalent term, but I would personally use PowerShell-idiomatic or maybe "PowerShellian" :D

Comment: "_the object returned is of type `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey`_" - Is there an online reference for this, and what this object can do? I wish Microsoft would include or link to such info in their [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849851.aspx) ([like Oracle does](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)). I just found [Get-Member](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849928.aspx) which would be okay for tinkering, but doesn't work for me (using PS v2.0).

Comment: [Microsoft provides plenty of documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey(v=vs.110).aspx) :)

Comment: But I'm not using C#, C++, F#, or VB; I'm using PS (v2). I don't know how to 'translate'...

Comment: Doesn't matter what language you use, the method signatures are the same. `GetValue("somevaluename")` is the same in powershell as in C#. That's the entire idea behind using .NET - having the same type system in every language

Comment: The more you know! Currently crunching through your `about_Providers` link. I still have _a lot_ to learn, and sad that I can give you only a single +1 for your replies.

Comment: Haha, don't worry, glad to help. Although, if my answer solves your problem you could also mark it accepted ;)

Comment: In the end, I did get my registry-editing to work, but it didn't solve my problem (of configuring an SQL server's Reporting Services). So it's only a half success for me, but still ten points for you.